# How to select specific rows of a SQL table without looping in .net

Tags: sql, arrays, select, parameters

Suppose I have a table called "Names"

```
ID | Name
---+--------------
1  | Bob
2  | Billy
3  | James
4  | John
5  | Tom
and on and on with thousands of names...
```

Suppose that I have written the following .net code to retrieve the names:

```
   public DataSet selectFromNames()
    {
        const string SQL_STATEMENT =
        @"SELECT Id, Name From Names;";

        Database db = EnterpriseLibraryContainer.Current.GetInstance<Database>("MyConnection");

        DbCommand command = db.GetSqlStringCommand(SQL_STATEMENT);
        command.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        command.CommandText = SQL_STATEMENT;

        DataSet ds = db.ExecuteDataSet(command);
        return ds;
    }
```

That works fine.  What if I want a function that has an integer array parameter specifying the rows of the names I want to retrieve?  How would I write that query?

I'm familiar with passing parameters as `@parameter`, but I have no idea how to pass in an array with using the string builder to write something like `where ID in (1,2,3)` which is ugly and error-prone.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Parameterizing a SQL IN clause?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/337704/parameterizing-a-sql-in-clause) If SQL Server you might find this useful [http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html](http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql.html)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suggest using a SQL Server UDF to help you. Here's an [article explaining how to implement this](http://blog.krisvandermast.com/UsingACommaDelimitedStringWithIdsAsInputParameterForASQLQuery.aspx).

Basically you'd create a UDF to split a `varchar()` into a table variable. Let's call it `dbo.MySplit()`.

Then you could:

```
string sql = "SELECT * FROM Table WHERE ID IN (SELECT Item FROM dbo.MySplitUDF(@csv));";
cmd.CommandText = sql;
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@csv", string.Join(",",myIntegerArray);
```

Answer (score 0):

how about this (using LINQtoSQL) ?

```
//...  
int[] idList = new int[] { 1, 2, 3, 4 };
var myNames = from n in db.Names
              where idList.Contains(n.ID)
              select n;
```

(lifted from [Creating IN Queries With Linq To SQL](http://blog.wekeroad.com/2008/02/27/creating-in-queries-with-linq-to-sql/))